# I have created a database on pythoneverywhere.com and I want to use it locally, in visual studio code project

Tags: python, mysql

I cannot connect to my pythoneverywhere.com database from my local project.

The error is:
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Thank you in advance!

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import pymysql as MySQLdb
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel 

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
    ssh_username='XXX', ssh_password='XXX',
    remote_bind_address=('bianca.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 3306)
) as tunnel:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        user='XXX', password='XXX',
        host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
        database='bianca$moviesdb',
    )
    connection.close()
# print('after SSH connection')



conn = MySQLdb.connect("bianca.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com", "XXX", "XXX", "bianca$moviesdb")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM reviews")

rows = c.fetchall()

for eachRow in rows:
    print(eachRow)



if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port=5002)
```

Answer (score -1):

Many things could be happening here: Timeout errors, packet sizes, etc. Also check your firewall settings.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html